# Find correlations using random forest

Tags: r, neural-networks, random-forest

Having data in this format:

```
id  stock var1_before var2_before var3_before var4_before var5_before var1_after var2_after var3_after var4_after var5_after
  1 stockA     -0.3957     -1.3106      3.3374  -1533.0000      0.3841    -0.4975    -1.6707     3.9367    -1.6377     0.6483
  1 stockB     -0.0201     -1.4492      2.6408     -1.3378      0.1647    -0.4107    -1.5982     3.7744    -1.5513     0.5484
  1 stockC     -0.3957     -1.3106      3.3374  -1533.0000      0.3841    -0.3557    -1.4963  3398.0000    -1.6543     0.4024
  1 stockD     -0.3729     -1.6134      3.4728     -1.5256    551.0000    -0.5223    -1.6512     3.9537    -1.6823     0.3634
  2 stockA      0.0498     -1.3222     -0.2173     -1.6596      3.5372    -0.2173    -1.6596     3.5372    -1.5497     0.4352
  2 stockB     -0.5075     -1.5452      3.6311     -1.7272      0.3317    -0.2003    -1.7075     3.4673    -1.3507     0.3594
  2 stockD     -0.3242     -1.3168      3.0884     -1.4142      0.4339    -0.4473    -1.6361     3.7018    -1.8195     0.3441
```

the variables are id: is a user stock: the name of a stock that a user (id) has an impression/sentiment for this. For every user the stock is unique var1_before-var5_before and var1_before-var1_after: are variables which are score of sentiments. For example var1_before is the sentiment the user has before a specific event and var1_after is the sentiment score the user has after a specific event. the same for 2,3,4,5.

I know that there are some user which can before and after event and moved from var1_before to var3_after.

For every stock how is it possible to find how most of users were in before label, for example for stockA var1_before and var4_before affect most but for stockB var2_before seems to exist most.

Is there any machine learning approach which could make it?

Comment: It may be useful for you to group the data-points based on the stock across various users, then calculate the correlation between var_before and var_after.

Comment: @rgk is there any better model to see how the stockA,B etc were in before and in after state?

Comment: to compare if the sentiment score has changed significantly one could perform a 2 sample paired t-test for every stock.